# Solve for $x$ a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve for $x$ 
$$ {{2}^{{{\sin }^{4}}x-{{\cos }^{2}}x}}-{{2}^{{{\cos }^{4}}x-{{\sin }^{2}}x}}=\cos 2x $$
but I don't know how to start. Replacing $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ by $y$ led me nowhere because of the right side.
One of the solutions I've found is $x=\pi/4$ but there could be more solutions though.

Comment: try $u=\sin^2x, v=\cos^2x$.  The RHS=$v-u$.

Comment: This seems to be the right choice to go for!

Comment: According to WolframAlpha
([link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%202%5E%7Bsin%E2%81%B4x-cos%C2%B2x%7D-2%5E%7Bcos%E2%81%B4x-sin%C2%B2x%7D=cos2x%29%29)) the roots are $x=n\pi +\frac{\pi }{4}$ and $x=n\pi +\frac{3\pi }{4}$.

Comment: Nice question.(+1)

Answer (score 17):

Let $u=\sin^2(x)$ and $v=\cos^2(x)$, then $2^{u^2-v}-2^{v^2-u} = v-u$ and $u+v=1$.
Thus $2^{u^2+u-1}+u = 2^{v^2+v-1}+v$.

Define $f(u) = 2^{u^2+u-1}+u$, then we are looking for a $u\in[0,1]$ such that $f(u)=f(1-u)$. However $f^\prime(u) = \ln(2)(2u+1)2^{u^2+u-1}+1>0$ for all $u\in[0,1]$. Hence $f$ is injective on $[0,1]$ and thus $f(u)=f(1-u)$ if and only if $u=1-u$. Thus $\sin^2(x)=u=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is the smartest idea you have!  Good job!

Comment: @NasuSama Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1)

Comment: I don't understand why $f(u)=f(1-u)$. I substituted 1-u for u, and I didn't get back f(u).

Comment: @Ovi I suppose you're referring to the last line of the answer. I think my phrasing there is throwing you off a bit. I claim that $f(u)=f(1-u)$ if and only if $u=1-u$.

Comment: But since $f(u)$ does not equal $f(1-u)$, how can $u=(1-u)$?

Comment: I think you still misunderstand my point. We are looking for a specific $u$ such that $f(u)=f(1-u)$ and I claim that this is only possible if $u=1-u$, since $f$ is injective.

Comment: Oh ok I realized where I was confused. I didn't know why specifically you were looking for a u such that @f(u)=f(1-u)@, but now I see that @f(u)=f(v)@ and @v=1-u$. Very nice solution, +1! How did you think of this?

Answer (score 1):

The left side of the equation is greater than $0$ if and only if the right side is less than $0$, and vice versa. This follows from
$$ [\sin^4x-\cos^2x]-[\cos^4x-\sin^2x]=-\left(\cos^2x-\sin^2x\right)(\cos^2x+\sin^2x+1)=-2\cos2x.$$
Therefore all possible solutions correspond to zeros of the right hand side (which are also automatically zeroes of the left hand side). This gives $x=\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi\mathbb{Z},\pm\frac{3\pi}{4}+2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $\cos^2x=a,$

$\sin^4x-\cos^2x=(1-a)^2-a=a^2-3a+1$ and $\cos^4x-\sin^2x=a^2-(1-a)=a^2+a-1$

So we get, $2^{a^2-3a+1}-2^{a^2+a-1}=2a-1$

or, $2^{a^2-3a+1}(1-2^{4a-2})=2a-1$

If $2a-1>0,$  $4a-2>0\implies 2^{4a-2}>2^0=1\implies $ the left hand side is $<0$

Similarly, if $2a-1<0$  the right hand side is $>0$

If $2a-1=0,$  both sides become $0$

$\implies 2\cos^2x-1=0\iff \cos2x=0\implies 2x=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}2$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

We study the injectivity function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow R$, $f(t)= 2^{t^{2}+t-1}+t$

$f(t)= f(u)$ involving $t=u$ and then $sin^{2}x=cos^{2}x$...

Comment: This answer is brilliant since it requires no calculus. Thank you.

Comment: Why's $f(u)=f(t) \implies{?} u=t $?

Comment: The function f is strictly increasing functions are obtained by operations with strictly increasing. Any function strictly monotone is injective function.